# middleman blog at /blog with already made static site?

Tags: middleman, static-site

I already have a site up that's using middleman (template=html), but now I want to add a blog to that site, so that when you go to example.com you see the homepage (not blog), and when you go to example.com/blog you see the blog.

This seems like it should be really easy, but it's my first time working with middleman, so apologies. Every article I read is either setting up a non-blog site, or setting up a site with the blog on the front page.

So what's the best way to do the above?

EDIT: to clarify, right now I have it set up with source/index.html.erb as my homepage, and source/blog.html.erb has my blog html. the articles show up in a list, but the "recent articles" and "tags" sections don't show up, so seems like this isn't the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup your middleman as a blog. You can create a static page in middleman blog. I suggest you to create two layout, one for static and other for your blog ([read more about middleman layout here](https://middlemanapp.com/basics/layouts/))

Then set your blog configuration to use blog layout from `config.rb`. For your static page, call static layout using YAML frontmatter like this:

```
---
layout: static
---
```

Hope this helps :)